# Configure Automatic Profile Selection for NetworkManager

Tags: networkmanager

I have a Debian system with multiple network interfaces. For the uplink interface (`eno2`), two different profiles are valid, depending whether the system is:

- on my desk
- in the lab

I would want NetworkManager to always automatically try to connect using the *Lab*  connection (profile) for `eno2`, as I can manually select the other profile, if necessary. How can I control which connection NetworkManager applies?

Comment: You could create a connection profile for it and add a startup script containing `nmcli connection up id <connection-id>` ([more info](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-configure-and-manage-network-connections-using-nmcli/?PageSpeed=noscript).

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager

NetworkManager by default does not manage any wired network connections, those defined in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

You can tell NetworkManager to manage these by setting `managed=true` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

You should then be able to define the configuration of NetworkManager, including the network you wish it to always attempt to connect.

Comment: thank you for the reply. However, on a recent Debian installation (9.3), the only interface defined in `/etc/network/interfaces` is the loop back interface, all others are by default managed by NetworkManager. In addition, my question was about controlling _which_ connection NetworkManager applies.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have a working solution for this.

First of all, the options available in the GUI for NetworkManager (**network-manager-applet**?) is rather limited, so it's better to use the command line interface directly, which is `nmcli`.

Tecmint had a reasonably good [article](https://www.tecmint.com/configure-network-connections-using-nmcli-tool-in-linux/) on using nmcli.

The solution works by configuring [Connection options](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-settings.html) as follows:

- for each interface, I configure the default *Connection* so that it is **bound to the interface** with the `interface-name` option and only one such connection is bound per interface.
- for all other *Connections*, I set the option `autoconnect=false` so that the Connection will only be applied, if I request so.

I think this should work. Will have to test.